# Attachments by Reference in Outlook Templates

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2013, templates, attachments

I'm sure that this isn't easily achievable, as I can't seem to find any information about it anywhere. Nonetheless, it doesn't hurt to ask.

At work, I have a single computer with multiple email accounts. Each account has templates assigned to it, and these templates contain a common set of attachments.

Is there any way that I can have Outlook refer to these attachments in their original locations instead of them actually being attached to the template?

I ask because the attachments in question (PDF files) get updated on a regular basis, and it's quite a mission to update each template.

Answer (score 0):

There is a way, but this is kind of tricky. First of all, you need to attach your PDFs to templates **by reference**. This will require to set [PR_ATTACH_METHOD](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc815439(v=office.15).aspx) MAPI property to ATTACH_BY_REF_ONLY (value of 4) and set some additional properties like PR_ATTACH_PATHNAME / PR_ATTACH_LONG_PATHNAME pointing to PDF file and save the template.

Then, you will need to replace the resulting links with attachments themselves before sending each message (based on the template).

You can write VBA scripts (quite complex) for that or use third-party tools. As one of the developers, I can recommend free [Replace Attachments with Links](https://www.outlookfreeware.com/en/products/all/OutlookAttachmentsReplace/) and [Restore Attachments from Links](https://www.outlookfreeware.com/en/products/all/OutlookAttachmentsRestore/) utilities. There is a [tutorial video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=W5q5id8hyIA) available (it covers the commercial product, but it almost the same for free tools).

Comment: Thank you - I had a feeling it would need to be done using that methodology, though I hadn't yet seen the properties involved. I'll have a look at the third-party tools during the week.